# Incorrect syntax near ')' - t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please, I am trying to pivot this data, what is wrong with my code? I keep getting error - Incorrect syntax near ')'

SourceQuery:

```
CategoryID  AVGUnitPrice
1       37.98
2       23.06
3       25.16
4       28.73
5       20.25
6       54.01
7       32.37
8       20.68

SELECT CategoryID AS PerCategory,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]
FROM 
(SELECT CategoryID, AVG(UnitPrice) FROM Dbo.Products GROUP BY CategoryID) AS SourceQuery
PIVOT (AVG(UnitPrice)) 
FOR CategoryID
IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])
AS Pivot1
ORDER BY CategoryID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be

```
SELECT SourceQuery.CategoryID AS PerCategory,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]
FROM 
 (SELECT CategoryID, AVG(UnitPrice) UnitPrice 
   FROM Dbo.Products GROUP BY CategoryID)
   AS SourceQuery

PIVOT (AVG(UnitPrice)  
FOR CategoryID
IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])
)
AS Pivot1
ORDER BY PerCategory;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, another error came up with the code: Invalid column name 'CategoryID'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)") Modified Code: SELECT CategoryID,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]
FROM 
(SELECT CategoryID, AVG(UnitPrice) AS AVGUnitPrice FROM Dbo.Products GROUP BY CategoryID) AS SourceQuery
PIVOT (
AVG(AVGUnitPrice) 
FOR CategoryID
IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])
)
AS Pivot1
ORDER BY CategoryID;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CategoryID AS PerCategory,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]
            FROM 
            (SELECT CategoryID, AVG(UnitPrice) FROM Dbo.Products GROUP BY CategoryID) AS SourceQuery
            PIVOT (AVG(UnitPrice) FOR CategoryID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]))
        AS Pivot1
            ORDER BY CategoryID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CategoryID as PerCategory, AVG(UnitPrice) as AverageUnitPrice
FROM Products
GROUP BY CategoryID;
SELECT 'Average Unit Price' as [Per Category],   
[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]    
FROM  
(SELECT CategoryID, UnitPrice   
    FROM dbo.Products) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
AVG(UnitPrice)  
FOR CategoryID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])  
) AS PivotTable;
```